# IPython notebook: using quotes(') and dollar($) to pass string variable as argument to python script in command-line(!) | eg: abc.py -arg1 '$var1'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory

In using variables in the command line from a notebook cell, I saw that we can use put a $ in front of the variable, or surround the variable using {} , for example

```
!command {variable}
```

or

```
!command $variable
```

But when I was running a python script using the command line from a notebook cell, I would get errors

```
variable1 = '/path/to/directory'
variable2 = 7
```

`!Script.py -arg1 $variable1 -arg2 $variable2`

and

```
!Script.py -arg1 {variable1} -arg2 {variable2}
```

did not work.

After experimenting a little bit, I found that if a variable is a string, surrounding the whole arg with quotes got it to work.

```
variable1 = '/path/to/directory'
variable2 = 7

!Script.py -arg1 '$variable1' -arg2 $variable2
```

What is going on? I tried to look up this phenomena but I couldn't find anything.

If it makes a difference, I am using google colab colaboratory

Comment: Would it be too much work to tell us what the errors were?  I'm too lazy test this code myself.

Comment: A possible point of confusion is the `bash`, the shell, itself can do '$' expansions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
!Script.py -arg1 $variable1\ -arg2 $variable2\
```

Answer (score 0):

Any input line beginning with a `!` character is passed verbatim(exclude the `!`) to the underlying command-line interface. [[source]](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html#system-shell-access)

Passing a string variable after `!` character will pass only the string content, but not the `'`(quotes) symbol.
You need to surround the string variable with `'`(quotes) symbol in your line.

---

Using your example above, the two variables:

```
variable1 = '/path/to/directory'
variable2 = 7
```

When running this line:

```
!Script.py -arg1 $variable1 -arg2 $variable2         #wrong
```

it will translate to

`> Script.py -arg1 /path/to/directory -arg2 7`

the quotation mark is not passed to the command-line.

---

So, you need to add the quotation mark around the string variable:

```
!Script.py -arg1 '$variable1' -arg2 $variable2       #correct
```

that will translate to

`> Script.py -arg1 '/path/to/directory' -arg2 7`

the quotation mark is passed to the command-line. The command will work properly and your observation is correct.