# Run a python file with arguments in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to run a python (`test.py`) file in Colab. The file needs inputting some parameters, e.g., "--epoch", "--class_file". What I did is:

```
!python test.py "--epoch" 100 "--class_file" class_file
#class_file is a path string
```

After argument parsing, the `class_file` is not interpreted as the intended path string, but instead a string like `class file = "class_file"`. How did that happen?

Comment: What happens if you remove all quotation marks from the command?

Comment: It does not help. Still gives the error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'classes_file'

Answer (score 2):

Put the argument variable in a curly brackets `{}`: `!python test.py "--epoch" 100 "--class_file" {class_file}`.

Refer to a post [Notebooks: Passing string variables as arguments to python script via command line(!), using quotes And $, eg -arg1 '$varible1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330956/notebooks-passing-string-variables-as-arguments-to-python-script-via-command-li)